# How can I create array of Containers in javafx?

Tags: arrays, arraylist, javafx, collections, containers

I am wondering how can I create an array of Containers in Javafx.

What I mean is I like to create for loop, and inside I will create Panes and labels inside each Pane created.

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){ // I will create 10 Panes with each one has 4 labels in it. }
```

The thing is I have googled it and checked here as well, but couldnt see any example for this.

Can anyone help me with the logic of this.

Thanks

Comment: well actually when I creating the Pane objects it doesnt show up and giving error. here is what have I done in the controller. ` @FXML
    Pane[] listPane = new Pane[5];` and ` @FXML
    public void paneTest(){
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            listPane[i].setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;");
            listPane[i].setPrefSize(200,200);
            
        }` and I get this error `Jan 22, 2017 11:45:22 PM com.windows.scene.MenuTest1Controller listReceipts
SEVERE: null
javafx.fxml.LoadException: `

Comment: @FXML Pane[] listPane = new Pane[5] <- don't do this.

Comment: If you have 5 Panes you created with FXML you should do something like this. @FXML Pane your1stFXMLPane, your2ndFXMLPane, ...;  Also do Pane[] listPane = new Pane[5]. Then in your ini method do: listPane[0] = your1stFXMLPane; listPane[1] = your2ndFXMLPane; ...